# Editor control that manipulates XElement objects rather than XML text

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, .net-4.0

I have a program that configures itself from an XML file, but whenever that configuration changes I have to re-read the XML file and re-build the program's state from scratch.

However, I could also write it to simply subscribe to each `XElement.Changed` event, so the configuration can be changed at runtime without forcing me to ditch the state and re-create it again.

Is there an XML editor control (for WPF or Mono, preferably) that manipulates the instances of `XElement` rather than treating and manipulating the document as one big string?

Answer (score 0):

There's something missing in you logic.

- If whole configuration file is important ? If so - you solution is right - you should reload the whole XML file
- If something (3d party app ?) changed XML - how do you know about it ? May be the same program can kick some event and notice about changes ?

For XML using: the best method is using XPath and extract XmlElement or even collection of elements from whole XML. I don't think that there's a method to know if part of XML changed or get Event about it. To know that something changed you should check it with original copy of document - but I understand that another app changing it so....